# How do I begin toilet training a cat?

Tags: cats, toilet-training

I do not know how to begin (and continue) the experience of toilet training a cat.  How do I go about doing this?

Comment: This is too broad as it stands, could you narrow it down to  a specific portion of the technique rather than "tips and tricks"?

Comment: Do you mean "toilet training" as in using a litter box, or as in sitting up on a toilet seat and using the human toilet?  I ask because we have an answer for getting your cat to use a toilet here: http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/971/how-can-i-train-my-cat-to-use-the-toilet

Comment: Also the answer could be a bit different if the question was about litterbox training of a kitten vs. an adult cat resqued from the street. You need to nail it down to one case.

Comment: I think we can safely assume from the comments that nobody is quite sure what you're asking. I have, for example, tried training cats to use a toilet before and that's how I read this, but it could also be as others suggested. Please add some clarity and I can reopen.